# Is it beneficial to make variables const and/or static if they will never change during program execution?

Tags: c++

I have been working on my adventure game thingy. It has quite a lot of variables that just store values and don't need to change during execution. So basically all of the member variables, arrays, enums, and structs inside of the header file shown below won't change during program execution. Would it thus be beneficial to make the variables `const` and/or `static`? Should I make all of it `const`?

```
namespace Adv_Event {

    array<const char, 21> consonants{ 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'z', '\'' };
    array<const char, 6> vowels{ 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y' };

    string generateName() { ... }

    enum eventType { ... };
    enum eventRewardType { ... };

    struct eventAction { int Requirement; eventType Type; string OptionText, SuccessText; eventRewardType RewardType; string FailText; };
    struct customEvent { string MainText; vector<eventAction> Actions, ContinueActions; };

    array<const customEvent, 3> customEvents{

        "MainText...", {
            { 10, Type, "First option", "First option succeeded!", RewardType, "First option failed!" },
            { 20, Type, "Second option", "Second option succeeded!", RewardType, "Second option failed!" },
        }, { ... },

    }
}
```

I pretty much understand that `const` makes the variable read-only. I have read a little bit about `static` too and I at least understand its functionality for member variables of functions, but I'm not very knowledgeable about it in-general.

I have also been pondering whether it would be beneficial or not to make the array or struct itself const and/or static? However, I feel like this probably does something completely different than, for example, making a integer const and/or static.

Thanks :)

Comment: Why do you think it does something completely different?

Comment: "Const correctness" is a thing. "Static correctness" is not. Make things const if you can. Don't make it static. Static kinda breaks object orientation.

Comment: Using the const keyword can help the compiler optimize your code more effectively and prevent accidental changes to the variable and also make your code easier to understand

Comment: @user253751 I read somewhere in my research about `static` that it is one of the most overloaded terms in C++ and that it does different things depending on what you put it in front of.

Comment: Const also allows you to have references to temporary values  by keeping the temporary alive until the reference goes out of scope. Very useful ability. For one thing it allows stuff like `void parse_string(const std::string & str)` to work with `parse_string("I am the very model of a modern major-general!");`.

Comment: @MarkusVaittinen namespace `static` has pretty different meaning from class `static`.

Comment: @ThomasWeller Okay, thanks. So I could basically make every variable that won't change during execution `const` safely?

Comment: @MarkusVaittinen yes. You can change it later, if you find out you need to modify it.

Comment: *`const` makes the variable read-only* A caveat to this: The value cannot be changed after it is initialized, but it could be initialized with a different value every time, so it's not really read only.

Comment: @user4581301 not sure what it means, sound readonly to me.

Comment: @MarkusVaittinen Not what you put it in front of, but what it's about. It does different things on global variables, local variables and class members. These are global variables, presumably (namespaces don't change that)

Comment: @user253751 Yes, that's what I meant. Sorry, I didn't find the correct term to describe all of those things in one word :)

Comment: @sinanorl I was actually wondering if it optimized things. Very good to know, thank you :)

Comment: For variables, `static` at file scope means that there is only one instance and the variable's scope is limited to that file; it can't be seen or directly accessed from other files.  In function or block scope, the `static` means that there is only instance and the scope is limited to the block it was declared in; also the variable will not disappear after execution leaves the scope.

Comment: For functions & methods, `static` will restrict the scope or accessibility of free standing functions to file scope; entities outside of the file will not be able to access the file.  When `static` is applied to a class method,  the method doesn't need a class instance to access the method.